# TypeScript React Context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I created a User Context API (code here: https://pastebin.pl/view/e0b5e0f4), then I can read it like this:

```
const { state: { user }, dispatch} = useUserContext();
```

but I want to do it like this (array instead of object):

```
const [{ user }, dispatch] = useUserContext();
```

So I change UserProvider to:

```
export const UserProvider: React.FC<UserProviderProps> = ({
  reducer,
  initialState,
  children,
}) => (
  <UserContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </UserContext.Provider>
);
```

And I got tip error message:

```
Type '[UserProps, Dispatch<UserActions>]' is not assignable to type 'UserContextProps'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(337, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<UserContextProps>'
```

I'm a bit new at TypeScript and I'm stuck here

Comment: TypeScript is just telling you that your JavaScript is wrong. You need to adapt the API like `const useUserContext () => { const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext); return [state, dispatch]; }`

Comment: Thanks, I need to learn read and adapt those tips :)

Comment: @AluanHaddad I did it like this:

`export const useUserContext = () => {
  const { state, dispatch } = useContext(UserContext);
  return [state, dispatch] as [UserProps, Dispatch<UserActions>];
};`

It's working but im not sure that is correct syntax.

Comment: That is what you wanted. You could shorten it to `return [state, dispatch] as const;` to infer a tuple type or add a return type annotation for target typing i.e. `useUserContext(): [UserProps, Dispatch<UserActions>] => {...}`

Comment: Oh, true. I did `return [state, dispatch] as const;` and function automatically made annotanion `const useUserContext: () => readonly [UserProps, React.Dispatch<UserActions>]`, so I don't need to add return type?

Comment: No. Inference is your friend but tuple types aren't inferred because that would lead to ambiguity with array types. I wouldn't do both. Use `"strict": true` in tsconfig, and it will tell you when it cannot infer something.